# Visual Studio item template: Replace with project name

Tags: c#, visual-studio, templates

I'm trying to create an Item Template in Visual Studio 2013 for an EF Code-First context class. I have it all working except I want a using statement pointing to a namespace within the current project. For example, when creating an instance of the template item within *ProjectName*.Contexts the using statement would be:

using *ProjectName*.Models

The problem is that I can't find a way to substitute the  part in an item template. As near as I can determine, $projectname$ and $safeprojectname$ only work in project templates, not item templates.

My template is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using $safeprojectname$.DAL.Models; // This is the problem line

namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    public class $safeitemrootname$
        : DbContext
    {
        // Constructors =======================================================
        public $safeitemrootname$()
            : base("$safeitemrootname$")
        {
        }

        // DBSets =============================================================
        // public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

        // Configuration ======================================================
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

In response to Hans comment, here's the output when I try to use $projectname$ ($safeprojectname$ does the same):

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using $projectname$.DAL.Models; // This is the problem line
```

As you can see, the $projectname$ substitution just gets ignored.

Any help would be appreciated,

Jason

Comment: No, that works just fine in an item template as well.  It is substituted with the project's Default Namespace value.  As set in the Project + Properties, Application tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the below MSDN link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehb4faa.aspx

The project name will come only when you have mentioned project name in New Project dialog box. So, if you are using it in existing project, it won't work. See screenshot below:

[image: Safe Project Name]

Answer (score 3):

Add `copyParameters="true"` in `Root.vstemplate` like below

```
 ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="Domain.$projectname$" CopyParameters="true">
```

Use `$ext_projectname$` in the code to resolve project name

```
using Provider.$ext_projectname$
```

Comment: This works (VS2017) zip file based multi-project template, but ProjectName="Domain.$projectname$" is also a name of the project folder as well as the Domain.$projectname$.csproj file as well, TargetFileName="MyNewName.csproj" for the project's own vstemplate file has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround - by using a custom template wizard, and retreiving the currently selected item in the source control explorer.

Since **CUSTOM** item templates are only available in the "add new" menu when a project node is selected in the solution tree, the project name (and all other info available to EnvDTE) can be determined and added to the replacementsDictionary.

```
using EnvDTE80;

public void RunStarted(object automationObject, Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary, WizardRunKind runKind, object[] customParams) 
{
    //Adding by template is unavailable in the context menu when selecting more than one item -> use index 0. 
    UIHierarchyItem selectedUiHierarchyItem = (UIHierarchyItem )dte.ToolWindows.SolutionExplorer.SelectedItems[0]; 

    //not null when selecting solution node (when adding a project)
    Solution selectedSolution = selectedUiHierarchyItem.Object as Solution 

    //not null when selecting project node (when adding an item) or when selecting a solution folder (when adding a project)
    Project selectedProject = selectedUiHierarchyItem.Object as Project;

    //Determine which kind of project node: 
    if (selectedProject != null)
    {
        if (selectedProject.Kind == EnvDTE.Constants.vsProjectKindSolutionItems)
        {
            //solution folder
        }
        else
        {
            //project
            replacementsDictionary.Add("$projectname$", selectedProject.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. Note that the "dte" variable used is the automationObject cast to DTE2 so you need a reference to EnvDTE80

Comment: Thanks Pedro - I've added a using at the top to make this a bit more clear.

Comment: How did you get dte?

Comment: This snippet of code needs to go in a custom item template class - I just added one from the template in Visual Studio, and then added this on top. But that was 5 years ago, not sure how it looks today ;)

Answer (score 1):

My colleague at work was able to find a parameter to fix it that detects the current project name.

```
$rootnamespace$
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, and unlike what the name suggests, it puts the full namespace of the folder the file is added to.

Answer (score 0):

TablesRepository:

```
    using $defaultnamespace$.DbContext;
    using $defaultnamespace$.Models;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
    namespace $rootnamespace$
    {
        public interface I$InputName$Repository : IRepository<$InputName$>
        {
            IEnumerable<$InputName$> GetList();
        }
        public class $InputName$Repository : Repository<$InputName$>, I$InputName$Repository
        {
            public $InputName$Repository(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context)
            {
                DbSet = context.$InputName$;
            }
    
    
            public IEnumerable<$InputName$> GetList()
            {
                return Queryable.Where(DbSet, x => !x.Deleted.Equals(true)).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
```

MyTemplate.vstemplate:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Item">
  <TemplateData>
    <DefaultName>TableName.cs</DefaultName>
    <Name>TableName</Name>
    <Description>Репозиторий</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <SortOrder>10</SortOrder>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <References />
    <ProjectItem SubType="" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$Repository.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">TablesRepository.cs</ProjectItem>
  <CustomParameters>  
      <CustomParameter Name="$InputName$" Value="$fileinputname$"/>
    </CustomParameters> 
</TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Result:

```
using MyApplication.Core.DbContext;
using MyApplication.Core.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyApplication.Core.Repositories
{
    public interface IItemsRepository : IRepository<Items>
    {
        IEnumerable<Items> GetList();
    }
    public class ItemsRepository : Repository<Items>, IItemsRepository
    {
        public ItemsRepository(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context)
        {
            DbSet = context.Items;
        }


        public IEnumerable<Items> GetList()
        {
            return Queryable.Where(DbSet, x => !x.Deleted.Equals(true)).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```