# Visual Studio C# Project Template: $safeprojectname$ parameter

Tags: c#, visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-templates

Visual Studio C# Project Template: $safeprojectname$ parameter

i'm trying to create a project template and i want to replace some file names to safeprojectname.

It works for source file however it did not work project file (.csproj) itsef.

```
  <TemplateContent>    
    <Project TargetFileName="$safeprojectname$.csproj" File="$safeprojectname$.csproj" ReplaceParameters="true">      
      <Folder Name="Definition File" TargetFolderName="Definition File">
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="$safeprojectname$.txt">$safeprojectname$.txt</ProjectItem>
      </Folder> 
    <TemplateContent>
```

**Is it possible to use $safeprojectname$  in project file naming?**

[MSDN says:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehb4faa.aspx)

safeprojectname:    The name provided by the user in the New Project dialog box, with all unsafe characters and spaces removed.

If it is not possible to use $safeprojectname$ in projet name itself i need know the **what are the unsafe characters that will removed**.

Comment: Something related to this question, refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26832203/visual-studio-item-template-replace-with-project-name

Comment: Yes, i saw that topic. my problem is a bit different. $safeprojectname$ works for source file names but does not work for projectname itself. i need to handle that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i need know the what are the unsafe characters that will removed

Same as what Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars() returns.  So in practice any character in `:\/*?"<>|`.  Note how these characters do special things when used at the command line and when composing a full path name.  Having them appear in a project file name would cause lots of trouble.

Comment: what i need was to write my owns C# method that converts a string to safeprojectname. Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars() helped much. Thank you.

Comment: @tutalia How did you write that method and how did you get it into the template?